# How to get all points drawn in ios?

Tags: ios

I am drawing in a view using touchsMoved method. If we draw in slow speed then it gives all points through which drawing take place, but if we draw in a faster speed means moving finger in fast speed on the screen then it misses most of the points in the path. Is there any way we can get all the points which were drawn?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increase the speed at which touches are generated by the operating system. It is detemined by the hardware. The touch sensitive screen is only able to register touches at a certain interval. If you want to draw a continuous line you will have to interpolate between the points that you are receiving.